# Java Reflection get declared fields of unknown type SubClass

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I am writing a packet class that will hopefully be able to take all the declared fields of its SubClasses, add them to a list and then send them across the network.

Packet SuperClass:

```
public class TCPacket {
private PacketType packetType;
private List<Object> packetData = new ArrayList<Object>();

public TCPacket(PacketType type){
    this.packetType = type;
    packetData.add(type.getIdent());
}

public PacketType getType(){
    return packetType;
}

public List<Object> getDataList(){
    return packetData;
}

public ByteArrayOutputStream getDataOS() throws IOException{
    //writes data to stream
}

public void addData(Object object){
    this.packetData.add(object);
}

private void addDeclaredFields(){
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().asSubclass(this.getClass()).getDeclaredFields();

    for(Field field : fields)
        this.packetData.add(field);
}
}
```

The important line in this is:

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().asSubclass(this.getClass()).getDeclaredFields();
```

My hope, is that with this, i will be able to get all the declared fields of the SubClass ONLY, regardless of the SubClass type.

Obviously i could do something like this:

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().asSubclass(PacketRequestLogon.class).getDeclaredFields();
```

but i'd rather not hard code every packet type. What i am really asking, is will this.getClass() return the SubClass IF the method containing it: addDeclaredFields() is called from within the SuperClass, or will it return the super.

Comment: ..I forgot to add, i would test this but my class is nowhere near complete so i cannot run this in its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My hope, is that with this, i will be able to get all the declared fields of the SubClass ONLY, regardless of the SubClass type.

From [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) jadavoc (emphasis mine):

> Returns an array of `Field` objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this `Class` object. This includes `public`, `protected`, `default` (package) access, and `private` fields, **but excludes inherited fields**.

So you can be sure you're not getting the fields from the super class.

---

Tested your current implementation of `addDeclaredFields`:

```
class ASuperClass {
    protected int fieldInASuperClass;
    public final void addDeclaredFields(){
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().asSubclass(this.getClass()).getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            //edited this line for test purposes
            System.out.println(field.getName());
        }
    }
}

class ASubClass extends ASuperClass {
    private int fieldInASubClass;
}

class AnotherSubClass extends ASuperClass {
    private int fieldInAnotherSubClass;
    private int justAnotherFieldInAnotherSubClass;
}

public class AMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ASuperClass().addDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        new ASubClass().addDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        new AnotherSubClass().addDeclaredFields();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
fieldInASuperClass
--------------------------------------
fieldInASubClass
--------------------------------------
fieldInAnotherSubClass
justAnotherFieldInAnotherSubClass
```

Note that only prints the declared fields of the subclass, the inherited fields are not printed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, would this then:

this.getClass().asSubclass(this.getClass())

return the subClass if called in in instance of a subclass?

Comment: @LexWebb answer edited, added a test for your method.

Comment: I'm now having having trouble getting the data out of this field. I keep getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int. When trying to do field.get(); Any ideas?

Comment: @LexWebb that's a different question and should be in another post with the relevant code. Still, when you call `Field#get` you should pass the object reference from where you will retrieve the data.